Wordpress how to get block data, inner blocks of "core/template-part" blockName?
Wordpress version: 6.5.2
Folder:


PHP code:
$blocks = array();
$victim = get_block_template(get_template()."//home")->content;
foreach (parse_blocks($victim) as $item) $blocks[] = $item;
wp_send_json($blocks);

Result:
[
    { // <-- How to get this blockName data inside ? -->
        "blockName": "core/template-part",
        "attrs": {
            "slug": "header",
            "theme": "monolith-site"
        },
        "innerBlocks": [],
        "innerHTML": "",
        "innerContent": []
    }, // <--/ How to get this blockName data inside ? /-->
    {
        "blockName": null,
        "attrs": [],
        "innerBlocks": [],
        "innerHTML": "\r\nHome\r\n",
        "innerContent": [
            "\r\nHome\r\n"
        ]
    },
    {
        "blockName": "core/post-content",
        "attrs": [],
        "innerBlocks": [],
        "innerHTML": "",
        "innerContent": []
    },
    {
        "blockName": "core/template-part",
        "attrs": {
            "slug": "footer",
            "theme": "monolith-site"
        },
        "innerBlocks": [],
        "innerHTML": "",
        "innerContent": []
    }
]

Question
How to get block data, inner blocks of "core/template-part" blockName ?
{
  "blockName": "core/template-part",
  "attrs": {
    "slug": "header",
    "theme": "monolith-site"
  },
  "innerBlocks": [],
  "innerHTML": "",
  "innerContent": []
}

for the result shall be:
{
  "blockName": "monolith/text",
  "attrs": {
    "content": {
      "en": "Header"
    }
  },
  "innerBlocks": [],
  "innerHTML": "",
  "innerContent": []
},
{
  "blockName": "monolith/spacer",
  "attrs": {},
  "innerBlocks": [],
  "innerHTML": "",
  "innerContent": []
},

Conditional:

Using PHP, WordPress hook only.
DO NOT use JS nor React (@wordpress/block-editor)

Note:

render_block function only render the full code in front-end narrowed at <div class="wp-site-blocks">...</div>

